# Flask current directory

Tags: python, templates, flask

I want to easily reference same-directory templates from arbitrary locations in a flask app, for example:

```
.
├── app.py
├── src
│   └── thing
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── component.html
│       └── component.py
└── templates
```

Normally, I would have to `render_template` referencing the `templates` directory and go from there, but this is a pain. How can call the same-directory template consistently with a filepath from something like `component.py`, i.e. something like

in `component.py`

`return render_template(self.this_files_directory + "/component.html", data=data)`

How can I do this?

Comment: How about `render_template(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "component.html", data=data)` -- but the blueprint solution is likely better.

Answer (score 4):

You can reconfigure the default template directory when you instantiate your [application object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#application-object):

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='path/to/templates')
```

The "Flasky" way to do this, though, would be to use [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#blueprint-objects) to match your directory structure, so within `src/thing/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('thing', __name__, template_folder='src/thing')

from . import component  # e.g. your views for the blueprint
```

Then, within your `app.py` you import and register each blueprint:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from src import thing
app.register_blueprint(thing.bp, url_prefix="/thing")
```

Also, probably very worthwhile to read through this:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/#blueprints